# Launching Magic Image from text link TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

Is there a way to launch a Magic Image (into Lightbox) from a text link (not thumbnail) in TYPO3 ver.: 6.1.x. How would this link be created in the RTE?

Thanks,
Sam

More details:

Magic image is how we insert images into content through the RTE when we want to display an enlargeable image. The method is to show a thumbnail when clicked the fullsize image loads into a lightbox (in our case - Fancybox). This works without an issue. What I want to know is if there a way to have a text link ex. 'Apple Tree' created from within the RTE (we have to disable the toggle between RTE and HTML view as our authors do not know any HTML) that launches the image of the 'apple tree' into the lightbox with the same behaviour as a Magic Images.

I know we can create a link instead of placing an image and link it directly to the image file. With this method the image can be setup to open in a new window but not into the lightbox. What I want is how to get the text-link linking to an image to behave the same way as a thumbnail for Magic Images. I hope I am more specific and clear. Thanks

Comment: You NEED to be more specific, no one knows what do you mean by this question

Comment: Just added more information. Thanks :)